# promise.all with async and await not waiting for file write

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am confused with one behavior of async and await. I have a `promise.all` with a map calling another async function. inside that async function I have a file writing `fs.writeFile()` feature that has a callback. I want to do something once all the promise.all promises are resolved. But, **`fs.writefile()`** callback is always completing late. i.e. the console written after `promise.all` is getting printed first and then zip completion console.

here is the code:

```
ingite = async () => {
    let users = await storage.getData('users');

    let result = await Promise.all(
        users.map( async user =>{
            await datagenerator.fetchAllData(user.user);
        })
    );
    if(result) {

        console.log("All Done -->");
    }
}
```

**function that was called**

```
fetchAllData = async  (userName) => {



    await fs.writeFile(`${global.appRoot}/user_data/${userName}/test.html`, template, function(err) {
        if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        } else {
            zipFolder(`${global.appRoot}/user_data/${userName}`, `${global.appRoot}/user_zip/${userName}-info.zip`, function(err) {
            if(err) {

            } else {
                const file = `${global.appRoot}/user_zip/info.zip`;
                console.log('ZIP generated successfully for -->'  , userName);
            }
            });
        }
    });
```

Here, in the code `'ZIP generated successfully for -->'` for some users comes after

```
console.log("All Done -->");
```

Can anyone suggest me what is going wrong?

Comment: `writeFile` is callback-based, not Promise-based. Promisify it instead, so that it returns a Promise and can be used with `.then` instead of a callback. You need to do the same with `zipFolder`

Comment: Use `const fs = require('fs').promises;` instead of just `const fs = require('fs');`

Comment: If you need this to be sync you can use `writeFileSync` intead of `writeFile`. See the details [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)